# Error in geoip .dat after creating

Tags: python, csv, binary, geoip, maxmind

### **DISCLAIMER**

Yes, i know that .dat (geoip v1) legacy is **EOL**, but i really need it!

I need to create binary **.dat** (GeoLiteCity.dat) file from **.csv** files. For this i use [mmutils](https://github.com/mteodoro/mmutils) (`csv2dat.py -w GeoLiteCity.dat mmcity GeoLiteCity-flat-sorted.csv`) and myown [flat csv file](https://github.com/mteodoro/mmutils/files/2179351/GeoLiteCity-flat-sorted.csv.zip). When i done, i check it with, for example, ip 191.243.53.129 (BR, Abelardo Luz,
Santa Catarina). First i see it in csv and debug-log files:

`2148767 ["14702888 (('BR', 'Parana', 'Ampere', '', '-25.9167', '-53.4667', '', '20'), IPv4Network('191.243.48.0/22'))", "17135708 (('BR', 'Santa Catarina', 'Abelardo Luz', '89830', '-26.5983', '-52.2232', '', '50'), IPv4Network('191.243.52.0/22'))"]
191.243.52.0/22,3220386816,3220387839,BR,"Santa Catarina","Abelardo Luz",89830,-26.5983,-52.2232,,50`

all correct! BUT when i ask my GeoLiteCity.dat file "tell me, who is 191.243.53.129" with python (pygeoip, GeoIP modules) or `geoiplookup` i got: `US, Pennsylvania, N/A, Philadelphia, 19123, 39.964298, -75.144402, 504, 500`

### **UPD**

When i try to use **[geoip-generator](https://github.com/dankamongmen/sprezzos-world/blob/master/packaging/geoip/debian/src/geoip-csv-to-dat.cpp)** i got `Operation not permitted`:

`$ geoip-generator -v -o custom_geoip.dat -t GEOIP_CITY_EDITION_REV1 -l GeoLiteCity-Location-sorted.csv GeoLiteCity-Blocks-sorted.csv
geoip-generator: Reading block CSV and building the trie
geoip-generator: Done reading blocks, trie size is 3078613
geoip-generator: Reading location CSV
geoip-generator: custom_geoip.dat: Operation not permitted`

Here is the [stack trace](https://pastebin.com/xxkT7nyP) of this procedure. But if i try to convert with `geoip-generator` a little files (with 10-15 strings for example) - all work correct. In this case i got custom_geoip.dat without any errors.

So, maybe someone can explain me, why it done? Why info in .dat file is wrong? And how fix it?